Make objects move along a drawn path (C++)
I'm programming a game that have a feature allowing player to draw a path. And that path will be used to navigate object to move on it. I'm having a problem with the speed of the object. If players move their mouse so fast then it will increase the moving speed of the object and if their move mouse slow then it will be slow. I have a const speed for all object so Idk what is happening here. Anyone know about this ? Is there any keyword that I should look for ?
void ControlSystem::MoveAlongPath(const float& elapsedTime)
{
    if (!startMovement || selectedObject == nullptr || objectPath.empty() || pathIndex >= objectPath.size())
    {
        return;
    }
    auto banGame = BanGame::Get();
    VECTOR2 currentPos = objectPath[pathIndex];
    VECTOR2 nextPos = objectPath[pathIndex + 1];
    VECTOR2 direction = nextPos - currentPos;
    float distance = BanGame::Get()->Length(direction); 

    float t1 = speed * elapsedTime / distance;
    VECTOR2 newPos = MathUltils::Lerp(currentPos, nextPos, t1);

    float distanceToNextPoint = BanGame::Get()->Length(nextPos - newPos);
    if (distanceToNextPoint <= distance)
    {
        pathIndex++;
        if (pathIndex >= objectPath.size() - 1) {
            selectedObject->SetPosition(objectPath.back());
            startMovement = false;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            selectedObject->SetPosition(newPos);
        }

    }
    
    float t2 = rotationSpeed * elapsedTime*0.1f;
    if (t2 > 1.0f) t2 = 1.0f;
    //TODO rotate object
    /*VECTOR2 norDirection = BanGame::Get()->Normalize(direction);
    float targetAngle = banGame->AngleBetweenVectorReturnRadian(nextPos, currentPos);
    float currentAngle = banGame->ConvertToDegrees(selectedObject->GetAngle().z);
    float angleDifference = banGame->ConvertToDegrees(targetAngle - currentAngle);
    float interpolatedAngle = MathUltils::Lerp(currentAngle, currentAngle + angleDifference, t2);
    selectedObject->SetAngle(VECTOR3(0, 0, banGame->ConvertToDegrees(interpolatedAngle)));*/

    for (size_t i = 1; i < dragPoints.size(); ++i) {
        banGame->DrawLine(dragPoints[i - 1], dragPoints[i], 5.0f, VECTOR3(0, 0, 1), COLOR::BLUE);
    }
}

Here is my code. I'm developing my own engine but you can expect it work the way as in Unity Engine
